# How can I access another pallet extrinsic WeightInfo

Tags: weight, hook

In my pallet I use the `pallet_balances`, through loose coupling via trait `Currency`.
I use `T::Currency::transfer` in my `on_initialize` hook. In this hook I'm supposed to keep track of the weight I'm consuming, and return it at the end of the hook call.

I know that the weight for a call to `Balances::transfer` is set to:

```rust
// Storage: System Account (r:1 w:1)
    fn transfer() -> Weight {
        (41_860_000 as Weight)
            .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().reads(1 as Weight))
            .saturating_add(T::DbWeight::get().writes(1 as Weight))
    }
```

because I looked at it in the pallet `weight.rs` file.

What I want to do is access this value in my hook, so I can increase my weight counter and return an accurate measurement of what I used.

How can I achieve this? Where is the data available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply write a benchmark for your `on_initialize` hook, which when executed, will also run the appropriate balance transfers, and automatically add their weight into your final weight output.

This is the same for any pallet hook you use, since benchmarks simply execute the written code, any of those hooks should execute and be measured as a part of the benchmarking process.